# Android Persist A SnackBar Across Activities

Tags: android, user-interface

Situation : User has logged in , you show a snack bar which says successfully logged in and then navigate to another intent but the problem is that when you navigate the snackbar is cancelled / destroyed . how do we persist it across activities like the way a Toast does , no matter what activity you navigate to .. it stays alive and healthy and follows it's timeout .

Comment: Would using Fragments solve this? Just switch out a Fragment in the Activity, and the Snackbar will naturally persist. I am trying to figure out how to persist a Snackbar across rotations! :(

Comment: Yeah that already hit me but it isn't an option for me since most of my stuff are optimized for an activity anyways you could try and use the onpause

Comment: You'd have to put a lot of logic in there too

Comment: Yes, I found that just rebuilding the SnackBar from scratch in onResume works fine. I always keep my app state outside of my Activities, so the snackbar just populates itself in onresume identical to how it populated itself when spontaneously shown.

Comment: Don't use the SnackBar in your case.

Comment: If anyone is still interested , look into services , i know it's stupid to have UI and services together but it is possible , just like the way you could persist a widget on your screen of sorts . However the snackbar must be created and destroyed within the service , use this as a last resort . Best way is to use fragments though !

Answer (score 4):

You can make a custom toast similar to the snack bar:

custom_toast.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/toast_layout"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:background="#545454"
    android:gravity="left|fill_vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/toast_text"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and show it this way:

```
public void showCustomToast(String msg)
{
    //inflate the custom toast
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    // Inflate the Layout
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast,(ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout));

    TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.toast_text);

    // Set the Text to show in TextView
    text.setText(msg);

    Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());

    //Setting up toast position, similar to Snackbar
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.setView(layout);
    toast.show(); 
}
```

if you receive a ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5176): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

wrap around the code inside showCustomToast function inside this run fuction,

```
this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks, better answer if you don't need a click listener and just need to display a message.

Answer (score 0):

Make a wrapper around your view group and add it in each of your layouts. You can also use a window overlay. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-window-always-on-top)

Answer (score 0):

In fact, SnackBar should not be persistent or be stacked, as they are above other elements on screen. You can see this rule in [Google Design](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/snackbars-toasts.html#snackbars-toasts-usage)

But you can use a third party Material Design library here: [rey5137/material](https://github.com/rey5137/Material/wiki/SnackBar)

You can show it by call one of following functions:

```
public void show(Activity activity);

//parent should be FrameLayout or RelativeLayout so SnackBar can algin bottom.
public void show(ViewGroup parent); 

// It only work if SnackBar is already attached to a parent view.
public void show();
```