# Snackbar over multiple activity's

Tags: android, kotlin, android-snackbar

I have a snackbar but when switching activity's it stays on the original activity it had been activated. Is there a way to make it stay on screen when switching activity's?

```
    val mainSnackBar = Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
    val llp = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    llp.topMargin = 20
    llp.bottomMargin = 20
```

This is the code when clicking on a button to switch activity's:

```
mainSnackBar.apply {
                setActionTextColor(Color.BLACK)
                view.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.good_color))
                setText("Snackbar Message")
                val snackTextView = view.findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text) as TextView
                snackTextView.textSize = 17f
                snackTextView.layoutParams = llp
                snackTextView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_check, 0, 0, 0)
            }.show()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Persist A SnackBar Across Activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29989631/android-persist-a-snackbar-across-activities)

Comment: @JustSightseeing This post suggests I make a custom toast/snackbar file. However I would like to use the build in snackbar feature to keep it simple and optimized.

Comment: ASAIK, this would not be possible, you would need to make a custom snackbar/toast to achieve that